# Some documents load slowly during stress test, how reliable is NameCheap shared hosting?

Tags: performance, testing, node-js, namecheap, react-js

I have hosted a NodeJS React application into my NameCheap shared hosting account.
My Apache Benchmark giving this output while I am trying to stress test my site:

```
ab -n 100 -c 5 -C "somecookie=rawr" http://example.com/
```

> ```
> This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1807734 $>
> Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
> Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
>
> Benchmarking example.com (be patient).....done
>
>
> Server Software:        Apache
> Server Hostname:        example.com
> Server Port:            80
>
> Document Path:          /
> Document Length:        931 bytes
>
> Concurrency Level:      5
> Time taken for tests:   19.073 seconds
> Complete requests:      100
> Failed requests:        0
> Total transferred:      133200 bytes
> HTML transferred:       93100 bytes
> Requests per second:    5.24 [#/sec] (mean)
> Time per request:       953.661 [ms] (mean)
> Time per request:       190.732 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
> Transfer rate:          6.82 [Kbytes/sec] received
>
> Connection Times (ms)
>               min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
> Connect:      296  434 207.9    409    1461
> Processing:   303  493 318.0    413    1893
> Waiting:      303  493 318.0    413    1893
> Total:        599  927 392.8    814    2358
>
> Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
>   50%    814
>   66%    889
>   75%    911
>   80%    917
>   90%   1573
>   95%   1928
>   98%   2253
>   99%   2358
>  100%   2358 (longest request)
> ```

My question is are this information correct?
When should I be worried with shared hosting regarding bandwidth traffic limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stands out as worrisome to me in your test results. Of note is that some of your requests take well over a second to load, but that is to be expected on any very cheap shared hosting provider.

Regarding the bandwidth limit, that is an internal NameCheap policy as the soft-caps for "unlimited" plans vary by hosting provider. Unless you are running a very popular website that serves very large files (consistently on the order of gigabytes per day), I would not begin to worry about the bandwidth metering on NameCheap's "unmetered" bandwidth plans.